# How can i add ontap functionality to each container in a gridview

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

So i want to make each container in the grid clickable to navigate to another page.

[gridview](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PM2Zi.jpg)

Comment: You can wrap your Container in a  InkWell() widget

Answer (score 0):

Wrap your container in an InkWell() widget, and use the onTap() function to implement the logic to navigate to the another page.

Answer (score 0):

You can use either [Inkwell widget](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/InkWell-class.html) or [GestureDetector Widget](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/GestureDetector-class.html)